# Open window in new tab after async api call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, window.open

I have this function I want to call followed by the opening of a page in a new tab after a user clicks an element in my VueJS application similar to this:

```js
const someFunction = async () => {
   const value = await api.someCallToApi();
   window.open('https://example.com', '_blank').focus();
}
```

I am not allowed to do this, probably due to the await resulting in the window.open not being a direct result of a user action(?)! Due to the way my application is setup the order of the api call and opening of the window in the new tab is relevant.

What would be a solid and modern way of tackling such an issue?

Comment: There's no "solid and modern way". You need to react quickly to user action, otherwise a popup can be blocked, depending on a browser and settings. The way this can be achieved depends on your case.

Answer (score 0):

In an ideal world, all asynchronous functions would already return promises.
But there may be still old libraries that use `await`.
You can create a Promise that wraps the `await` function as below:

```js
const delay = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, ms/1000), ms));


delay(3*1000).then((sec) => alert(sec + " seconds passed"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simulate a click event like this after your api call resolves:

```
const someFunction = async () => {
  const value = await api.someCallToApi();
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = 'https://example.com';
  link.target = '_blank';
  link.click();
  link.remove();
}
```